# ReactJS - Cannot restrict user input to letters only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to restrict user input to letters only but for some reason it's not working. I'm very new to ReactJS so maybe my problem lies here somewhere. This is what I've got so far:

```js
return (
    <input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]*" placeholder="Add Skill" onChange={this.updateField} />
)
```

type="text" and pattern seem not to work in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute is used to check against the input value when it is submitting.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

---

To restrict users to input only letters, you can use the `onKeyPress`

```
<input
    type="text"
    onKeyPress={event => (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122)}
    placeholder="Add Skill"
    onChange={this.updateField}
/>
```

This is the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

---

### UPDATE 1

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jeemok/pen/rqJaog

### UPDATE 2: `charCode` is deprecated

`key` return the typed character, so we may check if converting the key to number returns `NaN`:

```js
onKeyPress(event) {
  return (isNaN(Number(event.key));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there are several input fields and one submit button for them all for some reason.

Comment: @AnnaStierlitz I've added a codepen for it. Can you also share the code of `updateField` method?

Comment: Updated with React Codepen

Comment: updateField(event) {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });

Comment: @AnnaStierlitz I have updated the code in the CodePen and it is working still.. can you create one CodePen and reproduce the issue?

Comment: `charCode` is deprecated in 2023. Can you help us with an updated solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yup/Joi or other validator if you are going to use them several times and have more things to validate for that task as the regex are already there and tested.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup
https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi

Comment: Hey, can you add a Codepen sample where you solve the problem using yup/joi - that would be helpful!

Comment: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#SchemaValidation